# Exporting data from Petrel (Workflows) to Excel error - offset and length were out of bounds

Tags: excel, petrel

I'm working with the Workflows module of Petrel (Schlumberger) Software. At one point I want to export the result into a **xlsx** type file. But this action produce an error which is **"offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements"** and stop the workflows, also the excel file is not modified at all. I don't have a lot of freedom to access  the lower level coding in this module. any suggestion regarding how to deal with this problem is appreciated.

[image: This is the section of workflow and the problematic line is shown with the red rectangular :]

[image: It's the typical chart that is being copied]

the function copies two set of data (x and y) and into a sheet of excel and draw the chart using the data in that sheet to draw the chart. It's about 100 set points of (x,y)

This is the Petrel Log:

> Type : System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
>   Source : mscorlib
>   Help link : 
>   ParamName : 
>   Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite : Void ThrowArgumentException(System.ExceptionResource)
>   HResult : -2147024809
>   Stack Trace :    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Reverse(Int32 index, Int32 count)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.XmlReaders.Excel2007Parser.ParseThemeColors(XmlReader reader, Dictionary`2& dicThemeColors)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.XmlReaders.Excel2007Parser.ParseThemeElements(XmlReader reader)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.XmlReaders.Excel2007Parser.ParseThemes(XmlReader reader)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.XmlSerialization.FileDataHolder.ParseWorkbook(List`1& themeColors, Boolean parseOnDemand)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.XmlSerialization.FileDataHolder.ParseDocument(List`1& themeColors, Boolean parseOnDemand)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.ApplicationImpl.CreateWorkbook(Object parent, Stream stream, ExcelVersion version, ExcelParseOptions options)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.Collections.WorkbooksCollection.Open(Stream stream, ExcelVersion version, ExcelParseOptions options)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.Collections.WorkbooksCollection.Open(String fileName, ExcelOpenType openType, ExcelVersion version, ExcelParseOptions options)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.Collections.WorkbooksCollection.Open(String filename)
>      at Slb.Petrel.ExcelExporter.WorkstepExporterToExistingFile.PerformExport(String filepath)
>      at Slb.Petrel.ExcelExporter.XlExportWorkstep.InvokeSimpleCore(Args argpack)
>      at WorkstepCmd.run(WorkstepCmd* )

Comment: follow up update:
I found out that if I don't specify the file's name (then it will create a new file) it works without problem. And if I input the name of that file which is created by this workflow it will work fine too (adds more sheets to the specified file)